# Apply conditional formatting based on range of cells in another tab

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with a calendar with dates in row 3 and weekday names in row 4. In another tab of the sheet called 'Festivos' I have in column A a series of dates.
What I would like is that these dates appear in the calendar highlighted in a different colour, and if possible that the whole column is highlighted according to a conditional formatting.
I have tried with the 'match' function and with 'Indirect' but I have not achieved much.

thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your current setup, you can use this to highlight the whole column where the formatting is applied, the date must remain at `Row 3`:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Festivos!A:A"),B$3)>=1
```

Comment: Hello @Bryan
thanks for your help I just made a little change on your function. I have added a semicolon instead of the comma`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Festivos!A:A");B$3)>=1`

Comment: @user209336 Good to know it worked. It seems that you need to use a semicolon since your Spreadsheet is set to a country that uses that symbol instead of a comma. More info [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515)